# How to solve one variable given two variables and one inequality?

Tags: derivatives, inequality, boundary-value-problem

So I have a function:

$\phi(P) = \lvert (1-\alpha_2)^P - (1-\alpha_1)^P\rvert$

It is easy to show that $\phi$ is increasing between $0$ and $P_M$, where

$P_{M} = \lvert \ln\bigg(\frac{\ln(1-\alpha_2)}{\ln(1-\alpha_1)}\bigg)/\ln\bigg(\frac{1-\alpha_1}{1-\alpha_2}\bigg)\rvert$

and decreasing afterwards.

> Assuming $1 > \alpha_1 > \alpha_2$ > 0, if $P_{M} \leq 1$, how could I prove the following?
>
> $\alpha_1 > 1-\frac{1}{e} > 0.63$

I have stuck here for hours. I think it is a easy step to make it. However, I couldn't figure it out.

Any idea is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).